# jQuery not loading from CDN

Tags: htaccess, cdn, jquery, localhost, assets

I have a custom CMS, and for some reason jQuery will not load from the CDN. After sitting on this for days, I remember I made a change the the .htaccess file but not sure if it's really the cause.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|themes|assets|images|coobie|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Would this prevent:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

from loading?
The site is on my local computer, so it's requested form https://localhost

How I know jQuery is not loading: When I check the dev tools in Safari it's not listed in the scripts that are loaded. Also my scripts that were working, now log '$' is undefined. The link works fine if I head to it, so something is stopping it.

Comment: Remove it and find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to load a HTTP resource on a HTTPS page. Your browser may be blocking this external resource because it's considered insecure on an otherwise "secure" page.

Change `src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"` to `src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"` and see if that helps.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that one! Both answers are correct. So no offense to @Vasilis that I marked this one correct.

Answer (score 4):

Remove "http:" from the script src url, like:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js">
```

In case the problem insists, check if shows errors through Chrome Dev Console and paste it here.